# Zakat of cows calculation

Tags: c++, algorithm

For every 30 cows, zakat is cow of one years old, and for every 40 cows zakat is female cow of two years old.

EXAMPLE:

30-39 cows -> zakat: 1 cow of one years old

40-49 cows -> zakat: 1 female cow of two years old

50-59 cows -> zakat: 1 female cow of two years old

60-69 cows -> zakat: 2 cows of one years old

120-129 cows -> zakat: 3 female cows of two years old OR 4 cows of one years old

EXPLANATION:

30-39 category: 30 combination: 30

30-49 category: 40 combination: 40

50-59 category: 50 combination: 40

60-69 category: 60 combination: 30 + 30

120-129 category: 120 combination: 40+40+40 OR 30+30+30+30

Category is clear. Combination could be made only using numbers 30 or 40. Based on combination zakat is calculated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    int cows=67;
    int category=cows-cows%10;
    if(30==category)
    std::cout<<"1 cow of one years old";
    if(40==category)
    std::cout<<"1 female cow of two years old";
    if(50==category)
    std::cout<<"1 female cow of two years old";
    if(30+30==category)
    std::cout<<"2 cows of one years old";
    if(30+30+30+30==category||40+40+40==category)
    std::cout<<"4 cows of one years old OR 3 female cows of two years old";
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to make algorithm for making combinations that would work for huge numbers? Program should print zakat based on combinations.

Comment: Can 140 not be combined as 40+40+30 or 30+30+40?

Comment: Calculate the smallest common divisor of 30 and 40 (=10) to know, by which divisor you can divide everything for simplification.

Comment: Your program prints `cows` rounded down to one digit? E.g. `100` for `cows = 120`.

Comment: Should the answer only consider two rules (for 30 and 40) or an arbitrary number?

Comment: My program doesn't print cows, it print's category, I don't know how to make algorithm for cows.

Comment: @Sebastian 140 could be combined as 40+40+30+30

Comment: @Sebastian I edited code and question to make it more clear

Comment: Sorry, I meant can 120 be also combined as 30+30+40 and 30+40+40; or only as 40+40+40 and 30+30+30+30?

Comment: E.g. for 5400, divide by 40 ->135. This is the maximum number for 40 zakat (if no 30 zakat). Write a loop from 0..135. So many 40 zakat. Calculate the difference, 5400-40*n and divide by 30. So many 30 zakat.

Comment: sum of combinations must be equal to category, so 30+30+40=100 it cannot be combination for 120, or 40+40+30=110 it cannot be combination for 120, if you ask why can 50 be combination of 40 only, because the ruling is 0-29 -> 0 cows, 30-39 -> 1 cow of 1 years old, 40-59 -> 1 female cow of two years old, and after that we use general ruling for every 30, for every 40...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a number of cows, N.

The maximum number of two-years female cows (V2 for short) is floor(N/40). So, your zakat may have a number of V2 ranging from 0 to floor(N/40), which leaves N-40*V2 cows untithed. These obviously require floor((N-40*V2)/30) V1 to complete zakat.

Pseudo-code:

```
N := number of cows
MV2 := floor(N/40)
out 'Possible zakat due:'
loop i from 0 to MV2:
    V1 := floor((N-40*i)/30)
    out i, ' female cows of 2 years, ', V1, ' cows of 1 year'
end
```

You can complicate the algorithm to ensure that **when there are multiple combinations, only that with the minimum untithed cows is accepted**.

For example if you have 60 cows, the basic algorithm will yield from 0 to 1 cows of two years:

```
V2=0, 60 cows remain, V1=2, untithed = 0
V2=1, 20 cows remain, V1=0, untithed = 20
```

In this case, the (1, 0) solution is a cheat and has to be discarded. With 112 cows:

```
V2=0, 112 cows remain, V1=3, untithed = 22
V2=1,  72 cows remain, V1=2, untithed = 12
V2=2,  32 cows remain, V1=1, untithed = 2
```

Here, the closest solution is 2 cows of 2 years, 1 cow of 1 year.

In C:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int cows;
  printf("Enter number of cows: ");
  scanf("%d", &cows);
  int category = cows - cows % 10;
  int N, v2, mx, b1, b2, un, i;
  for (N = 0; N <= cows; N += 10) {
    v2 = floor(N / 40);
    mx = 40;
    b2 = 0;
    b1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= v2; i++) {
      int j = floor((N - 40 * i) / 30);
      un = N - 40 * i - 30 * j;
      if (un <= mx) {
        b2 = i;
        b1 = j;
        mx = un;
      }
    }
    un = N - 40 * b2 - 30 * b1;
    if (N == category) {
      printf("For %d cows, the zakat is:\n", cows);
      if (cows < 30)
        printf("0 cows");
      if (b1)
        printf("%d one years old cows\n", b1);
      if (b2)
        printf("%d two years old female cows\n", b2);
    }
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter number of cows: 140
For 140 cows, the zakat is:
2 one years old cows
2 two years old female cows
```

Comment: sorry, I don't know what programming language this is. Could you modify this for C or C++?

Comment: thank you very much, I edited your code a little bit, could you modify your code according to this? https://onlinegdb.com/_SpCdskUW